# JDBC Batch Job throws java.sql.BatchUpdateException

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, jdbc, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that takes an array of arguments and I add them all using a JDBC batch process. That process executes a stored procedure in SQL Server DB.

Here is the code for the Lambda function.

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        statement = connection.createStatement();


        for (int i = 0; i < notes.getNotes().size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("spInsertNewORUpdateNote '" + notes.getNotes().get(i).getNote_id() + "', '" + notes.getNotes().get(i).getUser_id() + "', '" + notes.getNotes().get(i).getNote_text() + "', '" + notes.getNotes().get(i).getNote_timestamp() + "'");
            statement.addBatch("spInsertNewORUpdateNote '" + notes.getNotes().get(i).getNote_id() + "', '" + notes.getNotes().get(i).getUser_id() + "', '" + notes.getNotes().get(i).getNote_text() + "', '" + notes.getNotes().get(i).getNote_timestamp() + "'");
        }

        statement.executeBatch();
        connection.commit();


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("400 SQL Error Rolling back");
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("400 SQL Error");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("400 Exception");
    }finally {
        if (statement != null) {
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
        }
    }
```

This is the stored procedure that this code executes.

```
@note_id varchar(50),
@user_id varchar(50),
@note_text nvarchar(max),
@timestamp date

as
if exists (select * from Notes where note_id = @note_id and Users_user_id = 
@user_id)
begin
   update Notes set note_text = @note_text where note_id = @note_id and 
Users_user_id = @user_id
end
else
begin
   insert into Notes values (@note_id,@user_id,@note_text,@timestamp)
end
```

The above code only works when the batch only has one statement. It returns the following exception when I include multiple statements.

[SQL Exception from lambda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd3N2.png)

The first couple of lines are just me printing each statement before including in the batch.

I have scratched my head over this for awhile and no luck so far. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have found that I probably need to use CallableStatement Object here. So let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am calling a stored procedure, I had to use a CallableStatement object instead of Statement object.

I modified my aws lambda like this.

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        call = connection.prepareCall("{call spInsertNewORUpdateNote(?,?,?,?)}");


        for (int i = 0; i < notes.getNotes().size(); i++) {
            call.setString(1,notes.getNotes().get(i).getNote_id());
            call.setString(2, notes.getNotes().get(i).getUser_id());
            call.setString(3,notes.getNotes().get(i).getNote_text());
            call.setString(4, notes.getNotes().get(i).getNote_timestamp());
            call.addBatch();
        }

        call.executeBatch();
        connection.commit();


    }
```

It works now regardless of how many calls I add to this batch.